# Identify coordinate ring of a variety is subring of local ring of a point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

When reading Shafarevich's basic algebraic geometry page 84 chapter 2.  In this book, he writes: the variety V so that all its irreducible components pass
through x. Then a function f that is $0$ on some neighbourhood $U ⊂ V$ of x will be $0$ on the whole of V.

Why a function f that is $0$ on some neighbourhood $U ⊂ V$ of x will be $0$ on the whole of V? I know there is a identity theorem in complex analysis which states similar argument as this.

Comment: I'm not sure what the title has to do with the question.

Comment: Hint: can a continuous function which is zero on an open subset of an irreducible set be nonzero at any point?

Comment: Sorry for mistakes, title should be modified.  My question arises in Shafarevich's book when he proves coordinate ring of variety as subring of local ring of a point in variety. So, if someone has some better proof, I am very happy to learn that.

Comment: Hi, KReiser, as open subset of an irreducible set is dense in this irreducible set, so a continous function which is zero on an open subset is zero at this irreducible set, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The zero-set of $f$ is a closed set which contains $U$, so it contains the closure of $U$.

Comment: Please explain this more deeply, I still do not understand what you say relates my question.

Comment: If you want to know where $f$ is zero, it's natural to study its zero-set! Your question is equivalent to wanting to show that $V \subseteq Z(f)$.